# Set up VPN Server on Windows 7 that shares internet connection

Tags: windows-7, vpn, ics

While away from home I would like to route all my internet traffic through my home connection for privacy plus some other benefits.

Is it possible to set up a VPN Server on Windows 7 which shares its internet connection with any connected VPN clients? If not, can I route all my traffic through my home connection in another way without having to purchase new hardware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worked it out. It came down to the set up of the VPN Client.

Follow the instructions from the Youtube video [How To Setup VPN on Windows 7 as Home Solution](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1s5JxMG06L4)

In the Networking tab on the VPN Client setup, **make sure to uncheck IPv6** (this seemed to be the one change that made this work):

[image: VPN Client Network Properties]

[image: Speed result]

Not blazingly fast but for private browsing and even games it works a treat.

Comment: Thanks. This works with a windows 2008 server also. You also need to make sure the setting "Use default gateway on remote network" is checked.

Comment: @Simon Hartcher , Thanks for posting the solution, my question is as yours and I am trying the same solution, I can access lan but not the internet any ideas what other changes you made ? by the way my question is posted here http://superuser.com/questions/570600/can-not-access-internet-through-vpn