# Allow Internet Access with Default Gateway on Windows 7 VPN Server

Tags: windows, vpn

I have a Windows 7 box at home (which I'll refer to as Home-VPN) that runs a simple PPTP VPN server. I have a range of 2 IP address (192.168.1.10-192.168.1.11) to give out, although the server is only able to give out one concurrent connection. Ports 1723 & 47 are correctly forwarded to the server. IPv6 is disabled on both Home-VPN and the client. I setup Home-VPN just like this Youtube video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1s5JxMG06L4

I can connect to it just fine but I can't access the Internet when connected to Home-VPN, all outside web servers (eg. google.com, mozilla.org, apple.com) are unreachable.

I know I can uncheck "Use Default Gateway on Remote Servers" on the client side under IPv4 settings but that will route all my traffic through my current connection, rather than through the VPN, defeating the purpose of said VPN.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: What gateway does the client receive when they connect to the VPN?  Are the two IP addresses on the same subnet as the network with the access to the Internet?

Comment: When 'ipconfig' issued on the client after connecting to Home-VPN, the PPP Adapter (Home-VPN) is given a default gateway of 0.0.0.0 and one of the IP address the client is allowed to issue. It's current wireless connection IP information remains unchanged.

Comment: Why have you made your pool of IP addresses for the VPN so small?

Comment: Because the Windows 7 VPN server can only allow one concurrent connection. It doesn't matter whether I make the pool 10 or 100 address, there will only ever be 1 address connected at a time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set up VPN Server on Windows 7 that shares internet connection](http://superuser.com/questions/288356/set-up-vpn-server-on-windows-7-that-shares-internet-connection)

Comment: IPv6 was disabled on both sides and there is no change.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your update, you need to assure that the VPN server provides the clinet with an IP and a default gateway and likley DNS server addresses.  What happens if you allow the VPN client to receive an address via DHCP rather than assigning the two you have?  Can you confirm that the 192.168.1.10 &.11 addresses are on the local subnet which contains the gateway that the host system uses?

Comment: If I attempt to allow Home-VPN to issue its own address via DHCP, the client is prompted with an Error 720: The client is unable to connect to the sever.

My router setup has two routers, one from the cable company, one for myself. The cable company has 192.168.1.1, my own has 192.168.1.2. The cable company router issues DHCP from 192.168.1.3-192.168.1.254.

Comment: I don't think your second router (not from the cable company) is really acting like a router.  How do you have the two routers connected together?  Is the cable going from the LAN port on the cable router to the WAN port on your router or to the LAN port?  I've setup the Win 7 VPN before and could access the internet when connected to the VPN.  You also don't need to forward port 47 in the router.  The VPN uses GRE instead of TCP or UDP for that port.