# I have a windows VPN connection but it has "No Internet Access". How do I get it WITH internet access?

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn

I have been doing research on this topic for days, I have a windows 7 Ultimate machine running on a blazing fast internet. I set up a VPN on that machine, and would love it if the VPN can share my internet connections.

So what I want to achieve is connecting to internet THROUGH my VPN, in a way that my IP address actually changes after I connected to the server.

With that said, I DO NOT want split tunneling, I DO NOT want to un-tick the box to disable "Use Default Gateway", I want my server to actually able to share it's internet out to anyone who connected to the VPN.

Disabling the IPv6 connection item does not solve this problem, and I researched forever now... Is there anyone that can help me?

I have searched on superuser as well, and is confident this is not a duplicate, because I do not want to disable default gateway, and disabling IPv6 item doesn't fix at all.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/135996/how-to-create-a-vpn-server-on-your-windows-computer-without-installing-any-software/)?

Comment: @Vinayak Yes I done that, which created a VPN service with no internet access at all... I need to manually input IP addresses for the IPv4 config as well, or else I get "error 702 a connection to the remote computer could not be established" when connected

Comment: I think you are missing some fundamental facts about what a VPN is. A VPN is a virtual LAN working over a WAN connection. This means that your users are still going to be limited to their actual connection speed to the underlying WAN; it doesn't matter if you provide another access method they'd still be limited by the underlying WAN connection speed. Split tunneling is what you want because it'll always result in fewer hops.

Comment: @krowe Thank you for your comment, I really appreciate it, however I still wish to have internet sharing over VPN. If you know anything that would help in this, please share your wisdom with me. I know that some later Asus router with VPN functionality is capable of doing this... But I would love it to be on windows 7...

Comment: [This question](http://superuser.com/q/288356/167187) seems to be asking the same thing that you are. Does that help?

Comment: @Vinayak That question is where I got the idea of disabling IPv6 item, it did not help me at all, it was disabled to start with cause I don't use IPv6

Comment: But did you also watch the video and follow the instructions in the video?

Comment: If that doesn't work, [this question](http://serverfault.com/q/928/218766) seems to be exactly what you're looking to achieve.

Comment: @Vinayak The video is just the video version of the first tutorial link you provided, I followed step by step. That question is exactly what I am trying to achieve, but in windows 7... I failed to see how NAT32 program could help me... Am I not seeing something from NAT32?

Comment: Actually, I meant the [next answer by Joel Spolsky](http://serverfault.com/a/2062/218766)

Comment: @Vinayak Yes, the default gateway is set to use the remote one, I believe the problem is with the server not the client.

Answer (score 3):

OK I just had what looks like the same problem and I solved it for me.

I followed this kind of procedure to set up a VPN

http://www.howtogeek.com/135996/how-to-create-a-vpn-server-on-your-windows-computer-without-installing-any-software/

I did the port forwarding.

But I was getting this

[image]

Notice the message "No Internet Access" and "No Network Access"

It was "connecting" though.

But the DHCP didn't seem to work

The fix was at the server side

right click "incoming connections" then properties, then networking tab, then IPv4 then see that screen come up pictured below

It was set to "assign iP addresses automatically using DHCP"  I don't as of yet know what on earth that did, but it didn't seem to assign IP addresses via DHCP to the client connecting to it.

I changed that to "specify IP addresses" and then entered them in and clicked OK. Then when I connected I got this

[image]

I have circled the part that shows you Internet access. Ths is of course a clear improvement, and indeed I can then ping 8.8.8.8 or www.google.com do \ip  I can click details in that window and see my iP there or in ipconfig.

[image]